# Import Alloy module using Java API

Tags: java, alloy

I'm trying to compute a total order of atoms using Alloy through its Java API.

So I was wondering: is there a way to include `util/ordering[SomeSignature]` using Alloy's Java API?

In `edu.mit.csail.sdg.alloy4compiler.parser.CompModule` there's a `addOpen` method but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find the addOpen method you are referring to in the [API documentation](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/alloy-api/edu/mit/csail/sdg/alloy4compiler/parser/CompModule.html) so I would suggest you to not use it.

What is preventing you from adding "util/ordering[SomeSignature]" to your module before parsing it ?

Comment: I was trying to use uniquely the java API (as in [this](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/code/ExampleUsingTheAPI.java.html) example), but there seems to be no translation for the "open util/ordering[S]" instruction. Well, too bad.